# add glassfish javax.persistence to gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, java-7

i getting this error

% gradle build
[ant:javac] Hello.java:2: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
Hello.java:2: import javax.persistence.*;

what should i add to gradle.build to include

/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/javax.persistence.jar

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
```

to your dependencies.