# Gradle compileJpaModelgenJava FAILED

Tags: hibernate, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot (v1.4.2) Application with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate (5.0.11.Final if I'm not mistaken). I added the jpadmodelgen-plugin to generate the metamodel classes for me, because, you know, I'm lazy. Unfortunately, when I run `gradle build` I get some nasty errors. The curious thing about this is that doing `gradle test` (which does real unit and integration tests of the complete application) runs without an error. I can even run the app in IntelliJ and life's great. It's just that my butler Jenkins can't build it.

```
> gradle build
:initJpaModelgenSourcesDir
:compileJpaModelgen UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileJpaModelgenJava

Mapping_.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.<snip>.model.domain.auth.Member;
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Member
  location: package com.<snip>.model.domain.auth
Mapping_.java:7: error: package javax.persistence.metamodel does not exist
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
                                  ^
Mapping_.java:8: error: package javax.persistence.metamodel does not exist
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;
                                  ^

100 errors
:compileJpaModelgenJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The error shows that not only are my own classes not found but javax.persistence as well. Here's the `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('gradle.plugin.at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins:jpamodelgen-plugin:1.1.2')
    }
}

plugins {
    id "at.comm_unity.gradle.plugins.jpamodelgen" version "1.1.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jar {
    baseName = 'services'
    version = '1.0.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jpaModelgen {
    library = "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.0.11.Final"
    jpaModelgenSourcesDir = "src/generated/java"
}

findbugs {
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportLevel = 'low'
}

javadoc {
    failOnError = false
}

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot, some Apache Commons libs and JDBC Drivers.
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        resources {
            srcDir "resources"
        }
    }
    /*generated {
        java.srcDir "${buildDir}/src/generated/java"
    }*/
}

compileJava.options.compilerArgs += ["-proc:none"]
```

Avengers Assemble! I need help, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had hoped that there's someone out there that knows a solution to this problem that retains the plugin, but, as is apparent, there is not. I found a different way by not relying on the plugin, doing a bit more work myself.

My solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23218255/1651116).

- The plugin was removed.
- Compile dependency to Hibernate's jpamodelgen.
- Defined a variable `generatedSourcesDir`...
- ... that is added to the main java source-set.
- Created a custom delete task `removeGeneratedMetamodel` that is required or otherwise there'll be odd compiler errors [like this one](https://github.com/google/FreeBuilder/issues/151).
- Added some options to `compileJava` that generates the metamodel.
- Added dependency to `removeGeneratedMetamodel` to `compileJava` and `clean` tasks.

Here's the build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jar {
    baseName = 'services'
    version = '1.0.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

findbugs {
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportLevel = 'low'
}

javadoc {
    failOnError = false
}

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot, some Apache Commons libs and JDBC Drivers.

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen', version: '5.0.11.Final'
}

ext {
    generatedSourcesDir = file("src/main/java/generated")
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        resources {
            srcDir "resources"
        }
    }
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir generatedSourcesDir
        }
    }
}

task removeGeneratedMetamodel(type: Delete) {
    generatedSourcesDir.deleteDir()
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        generatedSourcesDir.mkdirs()
    }
    dependsOn(removeGeneratedMetamodel)
    options.compilerArgs += ['-s', generatedSourcesDir]
}

clean.dependsOn(removeGeneratedMetamodel)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

I added the

```
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0.2'
```

dependency, and that resolved the issue.
I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27411441/7445342).